# I need to recover my drives and make them useable again

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I had recently got a computer that a teacher gave me, it had Windows XP on it.

I took out the 2 HDD’s from that PC and put it into a newer PC; a Compaq Presario Sr5100. When I did, I tried booting up Windows XP from both the hard drives but it had a boot failure, so I’ve been trying to format the disks from ubuntu 14.0.x from a LiveCD, and it doesn’t see the HDDs. But I tested each HDD to see if it would boot Windows XP and it let me boot them… To only fail.

What should I do to save these HDD drives!

Comment: sounds like you need the disk controller driver

Comment: The newer computer can see both drives, and attempt to boot from them, but you can't see either drive in Ubuntu? Are you sure they're not showing up in Ubuntu? Tried `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l` or `sudo parted -l` or looking with gnome-disk-utility (Disks) or `gparted`? And IIRC the old XP's won't boot on newer computers, some BIOS setting or mode conflict stops them, searching for that problem might find some solutions too (though running the now-unsupported XP isn't recommended anyway)

Comment: XP won't load if the system hardware configuration has changed (most notably CPU). It will end up BSODing. Not sure but there are ways around that - repair installation, I think.

Comment: [You will have to do a XP repair install](http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm) as suggested by AcePL, then you will have to enter a new valid XP license key to activate and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the age of the drives and computers, if you're dealing with IDE drives (wide flat cable) you may need to check the master/slave/cable select settings on each drive and whether there's a notch cut out of the cable. If you have two drives both set as Master or Slave on the same ribbon cable, the very best that you can hope for is that the system won't work with them; the worst that I personally have seen is a corrupted combination of the partition table from both drives being written back to (and corrupting) both drives.